# Apple Server - how to exclude a subdomain?

Tags: email, apple, subdomain

A client has an internal Apple Server setup in their office that manages their domain (let's say it is example.com).

I have setup a subdomain of example.com (test.example.com) on Google Apps as I want to use email addresses under test.example.com for an app that I am building. The reasons for *needing* GMail aren't important - but I need it.

The problem arises when someone from their office tries to email bla@test.example.com.

For some reason the Apple server seems to be saying - "I am setup to manage example.com and hence all subdomains of it. I have looked - but I cannot find a subdomain of test.example.com - so the email is undeliverable".

How can I get the apple server to ignore test.example.com and all of its email?

Answer (score 0):

If the server's configured as authoritative for `example.com`, it's authoritative for everything under `example.com`, too - working as designed.

Sounds like you're saying they have separate DNS records out on the internet that they want to be used for the `test.example.com` lookups?  Then their internal server needs to have `NS` record(s) delegating `test.example.com` to those remote devices.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically running a [split-brain](http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/1436#splithorizon) setup. There's no way to "exclude" DNS subdomains for a zone that you are running on; any subdomain of example.com will be covered by your local DNS. So instead, you should manually add the DNS entries for Google Apps into your Mac Server.

So take a look at the client's external DNS entries, and basically copy all of the mail-related ones into the Mac server. Internal clients will then recieve the proper information from the internal DNS.